# Full height page for tablets with no vertical scroll and fit content in one screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tablet

Ok, i will try my best to explain what i am trying to achieve since i am not allowed to add images here on stack, so here it is:

I have a design for tablets. The whole content takes up the 100% height of the design with just 15px of padding on top and bottom.

So, i have to make the design fit to all the apps available in the market, without having vertical scroll.

I have tried many solutions like using bootstrap with

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="main-content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, main-content {
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

also, i have tried reducing the size of elements in the page using media queries just to fit the screen vertically for different tablets.

The problem is, there are like 80 pages in the design and i believe this is not the best solution for this amount of pages and to add media queries for every single page. ( the page designs are different from each other, so common classes cannot be used )

Would like to know is there any other solution to fit the height of the page for tablets with no scroll.

Any help, suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you say your not allowed to add images, cause I can when I tried. That said, you can seperate the classes anytime and make them discrete. A little more work maybe.

Comment: how about you make all page elements absolute so you can position them relatively to the page edges (e.g. bottom:0px to attach to the bottom of the page).

Comment: You can try to use "vh" values to specify the size of an element, e.g. .main-content { height: 100vh }

Comment: this makes the the body and parent contents fit the screen. 
But if the child content is more, it overflows and the content goes out of the screen and hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
html, body, main-content {
    height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: this makes the the body and parent contents fit the screen. 
But if the child content is more, it overflows and the content goes out of the screen and hidden.